# Double series with factorials

Tags: calculus

I don't figure out how to compute it. Some help pls?
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=i-1}^{\infty} \frac{3^j}{j!}$$

Comment: Change the order of summation.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  We will be better able to help you if you give the context of the problem, as well as what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the order of summation thusly:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=i-1}^{\infty} \frac{3^j}{j!} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^j}{j!} \sum_{i=1}^{j+1} 1 = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^j}{j!}  (j+1)$$

Comment: Thank you. How may I prove the change of the order of summation you applied?

Comment: Both series are absolutely convergent - therefore, the change in order of summation is justified.  Practically, all you have to do is draw a picture of the summation lattice (or grid) and let that guide you on how the summation should be changed.

Comment: I need to draw a picture for a proof?

Comment: @Student_007: I just told you.  If you're looking for something algebraic, then here's a link; see "double infinite summation" a ways down.  http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/  You don't have to draw a picture, but it is the easiest way IMO.

Comment: that link is useful but no proof.

Comment: "adriank" has a proof applied to a different sum, but same idea: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=290900

Comment: I suppose there should be some simple proof for the general case.

Comment: @Student_007: it's pretty much the same idea; you should be able to work it out for yourself.

Comment: I'm not. I'm here because I do poor.

Comment: @Student_007: at this point I must leave it at that.  Since I do not know an algebraic proof different from the one I showed via "adriank," I am not going to spend time tinkering with different ways of demonstrating this principle until we strike that one you get.  I'm afraid you are going to have to go through the derivations I linked to - **draw the picture** - and work it out.  I'm sure you will succeed.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=i-1}^\infty\frac{3^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^{j+1}\frac{3^j}{j!}
$$

Comment: Thank you. How may I prove the change of the order of summation you applied?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that might satisfy your wish to avoid pictures. It needs a bit of justification, which I didn't provide (i.e. some thought must be put into defining summation and deriving its properties), but I hope it helps.

Define a set $$A=\{(i,j)\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N_0|\;j\geq i-1\}.$$ This will be the index set over which the summation will be done. For each $i_0\in\mathbb N$ let $$A_{i_0}=\{(i,j)\in A|\;i=i_0\}$$ and for each $j_0\in\mathbb N_0$ let $$A^{j_0}=\{(i,j)\in A|\;j=j_0\}.$$

You may visualize $A_{i_0}$ as the "$i_0$-th vertical slice" of $A$ and $A^{j_0}$ as "$j_0$-th horizontal slice" of $A$.

Note that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i=A=\bigcup_{j=0}^\infty A^{j}\tag{*}$$ which you can prove by checking that these sets contain the same elements. Summation (if defined in the appropriate sense, i.e. Lebesgue integral with respect to the counting measure) is countably additive, which basically means that you will get the same answer if you:

1. cut up your index set into countably many pieces, sum over each piece, and sum the results, or
2. sum over the entire index set in the first place.

Therefore, $(*)$ implies $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{(i,j)\in A_i} \frac{3^j}{j!}=\sum_{(i,j)\in A}\frac{3^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{(i,j)\in A^j} \frac{3^j}{j!}.\tag{**}$$
Now, note that $$\sum_{(i,j)\in A_i} \frac{3^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=i-1}^\infty \frac{3^j}{j!},$$ since $(i,j)\in A_i$ holds for a fixed $i$ precisely if $j\geq i-1$, i.e. for all $j$ from $i-1$ to infinity, and that $$\sum_{(i,j)\in A^j} \frac{3^j}{j!}=\sum_{i=1}^{j+1} \frac{3^j}{j!},$$ since $(i,j)\in A^j$ holds for a fixed $j$ precisely if $j\geq i-1$, i.e. it holds for all $i$ that are less than or equal to $j+1$. But then $(**)$ means precisely that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=i-1}^\infty \frac{3^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^{j+1} \frac{3^j}{j!},$$ which is the change of the order of summation we wanted.

*Comment.* The change of the order may be justified also under the usual definition of summation, but I strongly suspect that what I've written is conceptually simpler.